Question about $\int_{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{3 \pi }{2}} \tan (x) \, dx$
Let's consider:
$$\int_{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{3 \pi }{2}} \tan (x) \, dx$$
The graph of the function within the integration interval looks like this:

Sorry if the answers are obvious, but my questions are:
i. Am I correct that the integral diverges in Riemann sense?
ii. Am I correct that the Cauchy Principal Value does not exist (since there is no singular point between $\pi/2$ and $3 \pi/2$)?
iii. Is the integral $0$ in any known sense (in some other integration sense e.g. Lebesgue or in some regularization e.g. Hadamard)?
Thanks.

$f(t)=\int_{\pi-t}^{\pi+t}\tan x,dx=0$ for $0\le t<\pi/2$, so $\lim_{t\to\pi/2^-}f(t)=0$. That's a sense in which the integral is zero.

Cauchy Principle values are sometimes taken at two poles as here. Most commonly, this occurs for $(CPV)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} = \lim_{N \to \infty}\int_{-N}^N$. In your case, taking the CPV as Gerry Myerson shows is even more justifiable, as the two poles at the end points are by periodicity the same pole seen from opposite sides.

Cauchy principal value is a stretchable term.
